# Confused about partial intraclass correlation

Tags: correlation, intraclass-correlation, partial-correlation

Suppose the correlation between baldness scores in group 1 (fathers) and group 2 (sons) is 0.5. Furthermore, let the correlation between DHT and baldness scores in group 1 (fathers) be 0.4, and the correlation between DHT and baldness scores in group 2 (sons) be 0.45.

How do I then find the partial correlation between baldness scores in group 1 (fathers) and group 2 (sons), after adjusting for DHT levels in fathers and sons with the partial correlation coefficient when I can’t add the fourth important correlation (what the correlation between fathers and sons DHT levels are?

If you simply classify x as the father's baldness score, y as the son's baldness score, and z as DHT levels, I still can’t make sense of it. There’s something that doesn’t make sense here.

If the correlation between fathers' baldness scores and sons' baldness score is 0.5, and the correlation between fathers DHT levels and baldness scores are 0.4 and the correlation between sons baldness scores and dht levels are 0.45, then how do I find the correlation between fathers and sons baldness scores after sdjusting for dht levels when I can’t add the correlation between fathers dht levels and sons dht levels (the only things I can add with the 3 variables into the partial correlation is (xy=correlation between father and sons baldness scores - xz=correlation between fathers baldness scores and dht levels - and yz=the correlation between sons baldness scores and DHT levels) something is missing here, which is what the correlation between fathers baldness scores and sons baldness scores are (when adjusting for DHT levels), which must play a major part in the correlation between fathers and sons baldness scores after adjusting for dht levels. When I try to find the correlation between fathers and sons baldness scores when adjusting for DHT levels, the correlation is 0.356 when using the partial correlation formula by classifying the xy as the correlation between group 1 (fathers baldness scores)and group 2 (sons baldness scores), xz as the correlation between fathers/sons baldness and and both of their DHT levels, and yz as the correlation between fathers and sons dht levels. The part about all this that confuses me, is, the correlation between fathers and sons baldness scores after adjusting for DHT levels would (logically) also depend on the correlation between fathers and sons DHT levels. If the correlation between fathers and sons DHT levels is 0.1, then it would produce a much higher correlation than if the correlation was 0.8 - because if there’s a strong positive correlation between fathers and sons DHT levels, then a large part of what makes up the correlation between fathers and sons baldness scores (0.5) would be due to the fact that the correlation is to a large extent caused by the high correlation between fathers and sons dht levels when the dht levels are correlated with baldness scores. And if the correlation between fathers and sons dht levels are lower,then it shouldn’t make up a lot of the correlation, and correlation would still be high. If you simply classify x as fathers baldness scores, y as the sons baldness scores and z as dht levels. It makes no sense to me.

Comment: I tried editing your post but the awfully long sentences make it hard to understand what are you trying to say. Please consider editing it yourself by removing redundant information and consider writing shorter sentences.

Comment: I want to find what the  partial correlation between fathers and the sons baldness scores is after adjusting dht. The part of this I can’t make sense of, is the following: If we classify X as the baldness score of the father, and y as the baldness score of the son, and z as DHT levels. It’s really hard to explain shortly what I mean, but I’ll give it a try: The partial correlation is the correlation between x and y after adjusting for z. If we hold the z value constant (dht levels), wouldn’t the mediating effect of z also depend on the correlation between the fathers and the sons DHT levels?

Comment: What I mean is: the mediating effects of z (dht levels) on the correlation between group 1 and group 2’s baldness scores must also depend on what the correlation between group 1 (fathers) dht levels and group 2 (the sons) dht levels are.

Comment: The only 3 things in the correlation coefficients are: x (the fathers baldness score), y (the sons baldness score) and z (dht levels). Correlation- r(xy,z) … x= the fathers baldness score - y= the sons baldness scores and z= dht levels. I try to analyze the correlation between xy adjusted for z. But doesn’t it also depend on the correlation between the father and sons dht levels (which would be z and z? It doesn’t make any sense. In order for the adjustment of  z (dht levels) to have any effects on the partial correlation, the fathers and sons dht levels must also be correlated.